# Open an url in a certain outlook mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing a vba script to open a particular mail from outlook and then open a link in that mail.

So far I have only achieved the first part. How do I get vba to test which part of the body is a hyper link and to open it?

```
Dim stringsearch As String
 stringsearch = oMsg.Body
```

So now the searchstring contains the body text of the mail.

I know that the link will always begin with the phrase "SearchID" and will always be the last line of the mail.

Any help/suggestions/links are very appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged [excel-vba]?

Comment: Well, I am writing a macro in excel that opens outlook and searches for a particular mail and a particular link within that mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find the "SearchId" within the stringsearch and extract everything after it into "link".

```
dim linkLoc as Integer
linkLoc = instr(1, stringsearch, "SearchID")
dim link as string
link = mid(stringsearch, linkLoc + 8)
```